# How send keystroke to other app or window when a key is pressed?

Tags: .net, vb.net

I need your help.
*some users have marked this question as a duplicate question. 
This is not a duplicate question because I want to send a key when a key is pressed,not when a button is pressed. *
Please tell me how to send keys  outside vb.net form by using user32.dll.
Suppose, I have opened an app or window(my app is running and pressed "k" now the "k" key will be sent to the external app. I am using vb.net 2012
Sorry for my bad english. If you give the full code then it will be very helpful

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need to use user32.dll ? From what I'm getting you just want to send a key press to another application.

Sending the Key is very simple in VB.net

```
  SendKeys.Send("K")
```

That command will send the K key press to whatever application has the current focus, checking to make sure (or finding the current application with focus is a little bit harder but thats a different question)

Comment: Thanks for your answer but i want to send keys to windows explorer too. 
eg. For searching in explorer
and please tell me how to send "k" to any app when i press "a"

Comment: so when you push the k key on the keyboard you want an "a" key to be press immediately after, no matter what ?

Comment: @Someonethatmatters sounds like the other way round